Change format in value input using intl-tel-input using livewire
how to get country code or change format number in input field with intl-tel-input
this my html
 <input wire:model.defer="contact" id="phoneInputNumber" placeholder="Enter your Whatsapp Number" name="contact" class="PhoneInputInput" />
This my load from app.js
  const input = document.querySelector("#phoneInputNumber");
  window.intlTelInput(input, {
    initialCountry: 'id',
    utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@21.2.4/build/js/utils.js",
  });


